# Link in body mail android

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent, hyperlink

Hello I have the below code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "My TITLE");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My SUBJECT");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.link_app)));
sendIntent.setType("text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Mail"));
```

where link_app is:

```
<string name="link_app"><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.google.com">Text lablel that should be clickable in email</a>]]></string>
```

My problem is that the text is visible in email body but it is not a link.

Answer (score 0):

Some email clients like Gmail (some versions) are filtering the links, probably security issues.
We choose to add the link below the Text, to assure the client will get the link.

you will try also setting the link without the "http"

```
<string name="link_app"><![CDATA[<a href="www.google.com">Text lablel that should be clickable in email</a>]]></string>
```